# How do I remap CTRL-Q and CTRL-W to custom actions in TexMaker?

Tags: 16.04, qt, texlive

I am using TexMaker and I want to map <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> to "Comment" and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> to "Uncomment". I *do not* want to disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, but to change its default behavior.

In TexMaker, I get the following error on console:

```
QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Ctrl+Q
QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Ctrl+W
```

Comment: I had to do something similar with QtCreator because I use a super customized keyboard layout with a custom vim layout, where I needed to program in my own bindings. To accomplish that, I had to branch QtCreator, build its `.pro` file, edit its "fakevim.cpp" class, and build the project from there. Is that something you think you could do with TexLive?

Comment: I ended up using TexStudio with a fix: `alias texstudio='env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= texstudio'`

Answer (score 0):

If you do `stty -a`, you'll see that `^Q` is assigned to "Start" (undoes `^S` "Stop"), and `^W` is "werase" (word erase).

You can use the `stty` command (see `man stty`) to unset these, or set them to different values. Once you've done that, `TexMaker` should stop complaining.

Comment: If I remove the binding in texmaker, it quits (thats the default action).